# Can't ReOder DataTables Column using dynamic data

Tags: datatables

I just wondering why I can't reOrder my columns from ajax callback.

```
var ranks = '0,' + callback.columns // 0,1,4,2,5,3
table.colReorder.order( [ ranks ], true );
```

I got this warning.

> DataTables warning: table id=example23 - ColReorder - array reorder does not match known number of columns. Skipping.

But When I tried to do it like this. It's working.

```
table.colReorder.order( [ 0,1,4,2,5,3 ], true );
```

DataTables init:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ....
    colReorder: true
});
```

Comment: can you provide your datatable initialization and the table headers (if it was made through html)

Comment: I am just only using the normal initialization, but the data is stored from the DB and fetch via ajax.

Comment: have you tried using callback.columns instead of a rank variable? 
`table.colReorder.order( callback.columns, true );`

Comment: Yes, but still got the warning

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies on the array parameter.

try using

```
callback.columns.unshift(0) //adds the 0 in the beginning of the array, if this property is an array.
```

then use it as your array parameter in colReoder.

```
table.colReorder.order( callback.columns, true )
```

Comment: `var colOrder = callback.columns.split(',').map(function(i) { return parseInt(i, 10);  });` it's working on the first load of the the ajax, but when I tried to sort again it gives wrong order. By the way, I am using `.sortable()`

Comment: Here I got an idea https://jsfiddle.net/fgz73ay1/3/ , but when you click again the button it will reorder again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I Just use this function, first reset the table column order, then order it after 2seconds.

```
table.colReorder.reset();
var colOrder = callback.columns.split(',').map(function(i) {
    return parseInt(i, 10);
});
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
    table.colReorder.order(colOrder);
}, 2000);
```